# Select INTO Array or Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, alasql

I`m trying to set a result query into an array or JSON object using ALASQL:

```
var resdata2 = [ { A: "test", B: "testB" } ]; // Destination array

// Select first and second column values from xlxs
alasql('select A,B into ? from xlsx("gohan.xlsx")', [resdata2]); 

console.log(resdata2);                        // Shows one object for xlsx line!
console.log(resdata2.length);                 // Shows length of 1 only

$.each(resdata2,function(idx, obj) {
    console.log(obj.A);                       // Shows only 'test' 
    console.log(obj.B);                       // Shows only 'testB'
});
```

The spreadsheet has 18 lines which appear in the first `console.log()`, however in second `console.log()` and in each function, it shows only first line `"Test"` and `"testB"`.

Any ideas to show all lines?

Comment: Are you testing SELECT...INTO?  Otherwise I'd drop it and use `var result = alasql('SELECT A,B FROM xlsx("gohan.xlsx")');`

Comment: it returns to me result as undefined.
var result = alasql('SELECT A,B FROM xlsx("gohan.xlsx")');
console.log(result) //undefined

Comment: Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/ko54Ltv5/ and look at how A, B and C is not printed in order as the call is async

Answer (score 1):

Probably you nee to use callback interface:

```
var resdata2;
alasql('select A,B from xlsx("gohan.xlsx")', [], function(data) {
    resdata2 = data;
});
```

Here you need to use AlaSQL's callback interface, because XLSX() function is async.